# Can Virtual Server 2005 host Windows 7 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-server

I'm testing my application for compatibility with Windows 7 64 bit. I'd like to do this in a clean virtual machine. I know that Microsoft Virtual PC only supports 32-bit operating systems. Will Microsoft Virtual Server allow me to create a Windows 7 64-bit client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Microsoft Virtual Server 2005 R2 only supports 32-bit operating systems and software.  (See the *Virtual Server 2005 FAQ* page at http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserversystem/virtualserver/evaluation/virtualizationfaq.mspx.)

If you have Windows Server 2008 or later, Hyper-V **will** allow you to create 64-bit virtual machines.  (Of course, this requires 64-bit hardware with hardware-assisted virtualization and a 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2008 as the host OS, since the Hyper-V role only exists in the 64-bit editions.  See the *Virtualization with Hyper-V FAQ* at http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-faq.aspx.)

Comment: Thanks Jay. You also answered my follow-up question about the environment I will need to actually create a virtualized 64-bit client. I appreciate it!